# How webview2 runs in privacy mode

Tags: wpf, privacy, webview2

I have a WPF application that runs multiple instances at the same time

One control in the application is webview2. I think webview2 between multiple instances runs in a private mode without affecting each other. How can I do this?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is but the process model for WebView2 apps is described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/process-model?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077). There is a single browser process and one or more renderer processes per instance of your application.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you would call CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions passing in a user data folder that is unique to each instance of your application. I think this is essentially what "incognito" mode is in Chrome or Edge.